# Design pattern for position delimited text parsing?

Tags: java, parsing

I am working on a parser which parses delimited text. Example

position 1-10: field a
position 11-20: field b
position 21-30: field c
etc

Any design patterns I can use to implement? I believe I should be using Visitor pattern

Comment: Any reason why you need a pattern for this? Just because there is a pattern does not mean you must use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Visitor` pattern?! Just read the file line by line and use `substring()`:

```
String line = //...
String a = line.substring(0, 10);
String b = line.substring(10, 20);
String c = line.substring(20, 30);
```

Am I missing something? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I thought of it too. seems like i am complicating it. =p

Answer (score 2):

Although there is no need to use a pattern in situations when the format of the input text is always the same, a situation when the format needs to change. For example, if you think that your application *may* support additional file formats in the future, the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) would come in handy.

```
class LineData {
    public String a;
    public String b;
    public String c;
}
interface FileParser {
    List<LineData> parse(String fileName);
}
class FileParserFixed : FileParser {
    public int widthOfA;
    public int widthOfB;
    public int widthOfC;
    public List<LineData> parse(string fileName) {
    }
}
class FileParserDelimited : FileParser {
    public char delimiter;
    public List<LineData> parse(string fileName) {
    }
}
```

An application using this approach would program to the interface of FileParser, and the differences between parsing delimited and parsing fixed-width files would be encapsulated in the implementation of the `FileParser` that you pick at run time.